# Create Sections in Python

Tags: python

I am newbie to Python. I have large file with repetitive string through the logs

Example:

```
abc
def
efg
gjk
abc
def
efg
gjk
abc
def
efg
gjk
abc
def
efg
gjk
```

Expected Result

```
--------------------Section1---------------------------
abc
def
efg
gjk
--------------------Section2---------------------------
abc
def
efg
gjk
--------------------Section3---------------------------
abc
def
efg
gjk
--------------------Section4---------------------------
abc
def
efg
gjk
```

Could some provide me pointers to proceed with this.
I tried grep for the particular string, it gives me only the string in particular order. 
I want the entire log from abc to gjk put in a section.

Comment: Does a section always start with the same string?

Comment: What's the rule for sectioning? One section every four lines? Or create four sections of equal length? Or...?

Comment: Each Section contains string listed in the line, though the doesn't start with that string

Comment: Yes. One section every 4 line

Answer (score 2):

If a section is defined by the starting line, you can use a generator function to yield sections from an input iterable:

```
def per_section(iterable):
    section = []
    for line in iterable:
        if line.strip() == 'abc':
            # start of a section, yield previous
            if section:
                yield section
            section = []

        section.append(line)

    # lines done, yield last
    if section:
        yield section
```

Use this with an input file, for example:

```
with open('somefile') as inputfile:
    for i, section in enumerate(per_section(inputfile)):
        print '------- section {} ---------'.format(i)
        print ''.join(section)
```

If sections are simply based on the number of lines, use the [`itertools` grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to group the input iterable into groups of a fixed length:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

with open('somefile') as inputfile:
    for i, section in enumerate(grouper(inputfile, 4, '\n')):
        print '------- section {} ---------'.format(i)
        print ''.join(section)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it simple (as you say: one record every 4 lines):

```
with open ('yourfile', 'r') as f: lines = [x for x in f]
while lines:
    print ('----------------------------------')
    print (lines [:4] )
    lines = lines [4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a known starting point, you can trigger section headers whenever you see the section start:

```
>>> section = 0
>>> with open('bigdata.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'abc' in line:
                section += 1
                print ('Section' + str(section)).center(55, '-')
            print line


------------------------Section1-----------------------
abc
def
efg
gjk
------------------------Section2-----------------------
abc
def
efg
gjk
------------------------Section3-----------------------
abc
def
efg
gjk
------------------------Section4-----------------------
abc
def
efg
gjk
```