# Python:How to split file into chunks by the occurrence of the header word

Tags: python, list, split

Have a file:

```
NAME,ANDREW,AGE 20, BD 1979
NAT ENGLISH
OCC LONDON
INC 200$
NAME,SVEN,AGE 20, BD 1979
NAT SWEDISH
OCC FALUN
INC 100$
NAME,HANS,AGE 30, BD 1988
NAT GERMAN
OCC BERLIN
NOTE, HANDSOME ONE
NAME,LUDOVIC,AGE 40, BD 1955
NAT FRENCH
OCC BORDEAUX
INC 5000$
INTERESTS, FISHING
NAME,PETER
NAT DUTCH
SUMMARY,AGE:20,BD:1979,NAT:DUTCH,OCC:TILBURG,INC:1000$
```

I try to split it into chunks, where every chunk starts with 'NAME' word and contains unknown number of lines until next 'NAME' and of course the last chunk ends at the end of file.
The chunks I'd like to store in list of lists for example, at least it was my first attempt.
In general I need to iterate separately over every chunk later so storage method is to serve this later objective.

My hitherto code looks like:

```
start = 'NAME,'
end = 'NAME,'
flag_append = False
my_list = []

for line in open('sample_csv.csv').readlines():
    if line.startswith(start):
        data = line[len(start):]
        flag_append = True
        my_list.append(data)
    elif flag_append:
        temp = []
        temp.append(line)
        my_list.append(temp)
    elif line.startswith(end):
        flag_append = False
        break

print my_list
```

But it is not yet quite what I want.

My desired output would be:

```
[['ANDREW,AGE 20, BD 1979\n','NAT ENGLISH\n','OCC LONDON\n', 'INC 200$\n'],['SVEN,AGE 20, BD 1979\n','NAT SWEDISH\n','OCC FALUN\n','INC 100$\n'],['HANS,AGE 30, BD 1988\n', 'NAT GERMAN\n', 'OCC BERLIN\n', 'NOTE, HANDSOME ONE\n'], ['LUDOVIC,AGE 40, BD 1955\n', 'NAT FRENCH\n', 'OCC BORDEAUX\n', 'INC 5000$\n', 'INTERESTS, FISHING\n'], ['PETER\n', 'NAT DUTCH\n', 'SUMMARY,AGE:20,BD:1979,NAT:DUTCH,OCC:TILBURG,INC:1000$']]
```

Or schematically:

```
[[chunk],[chunk],[chunk],[chunk]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit 26.10.2012

Thank you all for very helpful answers.
I chose the answer from Kzhi because his solution does not omit splitting keyword.
Sorry I didnt mentioned this requirement in my question and your answers was relying on my clumsy code where keyword is omited in result.
Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Sections in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040999/create-sections-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would be an elegant solution:

```
token = 'foo'
chunks = []
current_chunk = []

for line in open('sample_csv.csv'):
   if line.startswith(token) and current_chunk: 
      # if line starts with token and the current chunk is not empty
      chunks.append(current_chunk[:]) #  add not empty chunk to chunks
      current_chunk = [] #  make current chunk blank
   # just append a line to the current chunk on each iteration
   current_chunk.append(line)

chunks.append(current_chunk)  #  append the last chunk outside the loop
```

So having file with contents:

```
foo
asdf
asdf
foo
foo
asdf
asdf
fooo
```

You'll get this result:

```
[
    ['foo\n', 'asdf\n', 'asdf\n'], 
    ['foo\n'], 
    ['foo\n', 'asdf\n', 'asdf\n'], 
    ['fooo\n']
]
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860441/split-diary-file-into-multiple-files-using-python

Answer (score 1):

You can do it starting from the following code:

```
>>> """NAME,ANDREW,AGE 20, BD 1979
... NAT ENGLISH
... OCC LONDON
... INC 200$
... NAME,SVEN,AGE 20, BD 1979
... NAT SWEDISH
... OCC FALUN
... INC 100$
... NAME,HANS,AGE 30, BD 1988
... NAT GERMAN
... OCC BERLIN
... NOTE, HANDSOME ONE
... NAME,LUDOVIC,AGE 40, BD 1955
... NAT FRENCH
... OCC BORDEAUX
... INC 5000$
... INTERESTS, FISHING
... NAME,PETER
... NAT DUTCH
... SUMMARY,AGE:20,BD:1979,NAT:DUTCH,OCC:TILBURG,INC:1000$""".split('NAME,')
['', 'ANDREW,AGE 20, BD 1979\nNAT ENGLISH\nOCC LONDON\nINC 200$\n', 'SVEN,AGE 20, BD 1979\nNAT SWEDISH\nOCC FALUN\nINC 100$\n', 'HANS,AGE 30, BD 1988\nNAT GERMAN\nOCC BERLIN\nNOTE, HANDSOME ONE\n', 'LUDOVIC,AGE 40, BD 1955\nNAT FRENCH\nOCC BORDEAUX\nINC 5000$\nINTERESTS, FISHING\n', 'PETER\nNATDUTCH\nSUMMARY,AGE:20,BD:1979,NAT:DUTCH,OCC:TILBURG,INC:1000$']
```

Also you can use `filter` function to filter out '' values and list comprehension to make each item a list instead of a string.

Comment: It will only work if the whole file content is glued together into one string. If the file is very large, this isn't going to be memory-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
token = 'NAME,'

my_list = []
data = []

for line in open('test.csv').readlines():
    if line.startswith(token):
        if len(data) > 0:
            my_list.append(data)
        data = [line[len(token):]]
    else:
        data.append(line)


if len(data) > 0:
    my_list.append(data)

print my_list
```

Answer (score 1):

This one does the trick:

```
in_string = """NAME,ANDREW,AGE 20, BD 1979
NAT ENGLISH
OCC LONDON
INC 200$
NAME,SVEN,AGE 20, BD 1979
NAT SWEDISH
OCC FALUN
INC 100$
NAME,HANS,AGE 30, BD 1988
NAT GERMAN
OCC BERLIN
NOTE, HANDSOME ONE
NAME,LUDOVIC,AGE 40, BD 1955
NAT FRENCH
OCC BORDEAUX
INC 5000$
INTERESTS, FISHING
NAME,PETER
NAT DUTCH
SUMMARY,AGE:20,BD:1979,NAT:DUTCH,OCC:TILBURG,INC:1000$"""

out_list = []
for chunk in in_string.split('NAME,'):
    out_list.append(chunk.splitlines())
print out_list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
content = open('sample_csv.csv').read()
res = filter(None, [filter(None, i.split('\n')) for i in content.split('NAME,')])
```

[['ANDREW,AGE 20, BD 1979', 'NAT ENGLISH', 'OCC LONDON', 'INC 200$'], ['SVEN,AGE 20, BD 1979', 'NAT SWEDISH', 'OCC FALUN', 'INC 100$'], ['HANS,AGE 30, BD 1988', 'NAT GERMAN', 'OCC BERLIN', 'NOTE, HANDSOME ONE'], ['LUDOVIC,AGE 40, BD 1955', 'NAT FRENCH', 'OCC BORDEAUX', 'INC 5000$', 'INTERESTS, FISHING'], ['PETER', 'NAT DUTCH', 'SUMMARY,AGE:20,BD:1979,NAT:DUTCH,OCC:TILBURG,INC:1000$']]

Answer (score 1):

Using your sample file-contents, I was able to generate this:

```
In [259]: %paste
def chunkify(infilepath):
  with open(infilepath) as infile:
    answer = []
    tinfile = iter(infile)
    while 1:
      try:
        chunk = [next(tinfile)]
        chunk.extend(itertools.takewhile(lambda line: not line.startswith("NAME"), tinfile))
        answer.append(chunk)
      except StopIteration:
        break
  return answer

## -- End pasted text --

In [260]: chunkify('blah')
Out[260]: 
[['NAME,ANDREW,AGE 20, BD 1979\n',
  'NAT ENGLISH\n',
  'OCC LONDON\n',
  'INC 200$\n'],
 ['NAT SWEDISH\n', 'OCC FALUN\n', 'INC 100$\n'],
 ['NAT GERMAN\n', 'OCC BERLIN\n', 'NOTE, HANDSOME ONE\n'],
 ['NAT FRENCH\n', 'OCC BORDEAUX\n', 'INC 5000$\n', 'INTERESTS, FISHING\n'],
 ['NAT DUTCH\n', 'SUMMARY,AGE:20,BD:1979,NAT:DUTCH,OCC:TILBURG,INC:1000$\n']]
```