# Split CSV file into multiple data frame based on common headers in rows python

Tags: python, csv

I have a large csv file which repeats data every few lines, I want to split it into multiple data frame from where the headers are repeated:
For example, I have these in CSV file:

```
Order   Time       Value
1       18:28:54    15
2       19:28:56    11
Order   Time       Value
3       18:17:13    42
4       19:17:14    50
5       20:40:12    30
Order   Time       Value
6       14:20:12    5
```

This sequence continues for more than 20 times in the csv file
and I want to have separate data frame created automatically:

```
df1:
Order   Time       Value
1       18:28:54    15
2       19:28:56    11

df2:
Order   Time       Value
3       18:17:13    42
4       19:17:14    50
5       20:40:12    30

df3:
Order   Time       Value
6       14:20:12    5
```

And so on...

Thanks

Comment: Check if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575702/pythonhow-to-split-file-into-chunks-by-the-occurrence-of-the-header-word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can split the DataFrame by the header lines.

- first we filter out the header lines by `df[df['Order']=='Order']`,at this moment the result Dataframe keeps the index
- we use the header index to split the orignal dataframe like a list,for example:the start index is 0,the next header line index is 2,so we split dataframe like this df[0:2]

but I have no idea about make new variable dynamic,so I append all splited dataframe to a list

```py
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
#filter all line which is header
split_lines = df[df['Order']=='Order']

dfs = []
last_idx = 0
for idx,row in split_lines.iterrows():
    #split line with the index
    _df = df[last_idx:idx]
    last_idx = idx+1
    dfs.append(_df)

_df = df[last_idx:df.shape[0]]
dfs.append(_df)
```

the example df with index like this

```
    Order      Time     Value
0      1    18:28:54     15
1      2    19:28:56     11
2  Order      Time      Value
3      3    18:17:13     42
4      4    19:17:14     50
5      5    20:40:12     30
6  Order      Time      Value
7      6    14:20:12      5
```